# general solution of ODE, not exact

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In http://math.jhu.edu/~szrebiec/images/exam1.pdf I found the exercises:

9) Solve the general solution to
$(1+ty)e^{ty}+(1+t^2ye^{ty})\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$

10) Solve the general solution to
$\left(\dfrac{y^2}{2}+2ye^x\right)+(y+e^x)y'(t)=0$

For 9): It isn't exact, only when I don't have a $y$ in the term $1+t^2ye^{ty}$ I received that it is exact.
$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(1+t^2ye^{ty})=2tye^{ty}+t^2y^2e^{ty}\not=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} ((1+ty)e^{ty}-1)=2te^{ty}+t^2ye^{ty}$

Maybe you can find an integrating factor? It only get more difficult when I try to find one. Is there an other way to solve it? Because it is an exam I don´t think that there is an error. The exercise 10) is from the same form.

For 10):It is either not exact and I have the same problems than before with 9). $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{y^2}{2}+2ye^x\right)=y+2e^x\not=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(y+e^x)=0$

Comment: 10) is strange as there are both three variables $x$ , $y$ , $t$ .

Comment: In 10), $t$ should be $x$.

Comment: no @xpaul, follow the link and you´ll see a t!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$(1+ty)e^{ty}+(1+t^2ye^{ty})\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$

$(1+t^2ye^{ty})\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1-(1+ty)e^{ty}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{1-(1+ty)e^{ty}}{1+t^2ye^{ty}}$

Let $u=1+ty$ ,

Then $y=\dfrac{u-1}{t}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}-\dfrac{u-1}{t^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}-\dfrac{u-1}{t^2}=\dfrac{1-ue^{u-1}}{1+t(u-1)e^{u-1}}$

$\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{u-1}{t^2}+\dfrac{1-ue^{u-1}}{1+t(u-1)e^{u-1}}$

$\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{(1-ue^{u-1})t^2+(u-1)^2e^{u-1}t+u-1}{(u-1)e^{u-1}t^3+t^2}$

$t((1-ue^{u-1})t^2+(u-1)^2e^{u-1}t+u-1)\dfrac{dt}{du}=(u-1)e^{u-1}t^3+t^2$

Let $t=-\dfrac{1}{v}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dt}{du}=\dfrac{1}{v^2}\dfrac{dv}{du}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{v^3}\left(\dfrac{1-ue^{u-1}}{v^2}-\dfrac{(u-1)^2e^{u-1}}{v}+u-1\right)\dfrac{dv}{du}=-\dfrac{(u-1)e^{u-1}}{v^3}+\dfrac{1}{v^2}$

$((u-1)v^2-(u-1)^2e^{u-1}v-ue^{u-1}+1)\dfrac{dv}{du}=(u-1)e^{u-1}v^2-v^3$